# REST API response only for certain feilds

Tags: java, rest

REST API Request:
`{ "name":  "abc", "sal":  "10000", "location": "Hyd" }`
**EmployeeRequest.java**
id, name, sal, location --> setters and getters

**EmployeeResponse.java**
id, name, sal, location --> setters and getters

POST : /api/employee --> this should not be change
POST API response :
expected:
`{ "id" : "123" }`

I dont want other fields except ID in a response

Actual:
`{
"id":  "123",
"name": "null",
"sal": "null",
"location": "null"
}
But i want response only ID not other fields for POST response, But its coming all the fields in EmployeeResponse.java

GET API(/api/employees/id) Response

```
{ 
"id" : "123"
"name":  "abc", 
"sal":  "10000", 
"location": "Hyd"
 }
```

But i want response ALL fields as a GET Response in EmployeeResponse.java

Is there any way to restrict certain properties wont be part of REST API response, even though all properties same Response class. ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the @JsonIgnore annotation

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "intValue" })
public class MyDto {

private String stringValue;
private int intValue;
private boolean booleanValue;

public MyDto() {
    super();
}

}
```

or @JsonIgnore on field level

```
public class MyDto {

private String stringValue;
@JsonIgnore
private int intValue;
private boolean booleanValue;

public MyDto() {
    super();
}

}
```

Comment: POST response and GET response I suppose to use same EmployeeResponse Class(i mention in the above what are the attributes) But few fields required for POST and few for GET
Ex:
POST Response
 {
  "id" : "123"
 }

 GET Response
  {
    id
    name
    sal
    location
  }
 if we use @jsonIgnore, it will be issue for GET response. Please suggest on this.

Comment: for custom serialization you can use JsonFilter annotation as mentioned in https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria but it is quite complex and considering that you can just duplicate the EmployeeResponse  class with different name like EmployeeResponse and EmployeeRequest and use it